# Whenany() on task list is exiting the program

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a console application where i am using TPL and it exits when I hit whenany on tasks..I am new to threading, can someone guide me in right direction (I have executed RunJob separately, it has no exceptions)..so i am not sure on how to debug from here.

Here is the code:

```
// Program.cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TaskHelper helper = new TaskHelper();
    helper.StartProcessing();
}

// TaskHelper Class
public async void StartProcessing()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();
    int taskNum = _queueList.Count < maxThreads ? _queueList.Count : maxThreads;
    for (int i = 0; i < taskNum; i++)
    {
        UCMDo doObj;
        if (_taskQueue.TryDequeue(out doObj))
        {
            tasks.Add(RunOps(doObj));
        }
    }

    while (tasks.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            // Program exits here when its hitting WhenAny line
            var t = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
            tasks.Remove(t);
            await t;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception exc) { }
        finally
        {
           // add to tasks, and RunOps
        }
    }
}

async Task<bool> RunOps(UCMDo doJ)
{
    var result = await Task.Run(() => UCMFactory.RunJob(_job, doJ));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling that method?

Comment: Ideally, post a short but complete program (with rather more consistent indentation) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Jon, I have updated the code.Can you please let me know if i am missing to put my problem accross

Comment: Well it's still not a short but complete program. It's not something I can copy, paste, compile, run with no otther changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that you call `StartProcessing` without awaiting it (you can't since it's `async void`) and so the program reaches the end of `Main` and ends while the operation in `StartProcessing` is still running.

`StartProcessing` should return a task and you should be waiting for that task to complete. That's usually done by awaiting the task (i.e. `await helper.StartProcessing()`) but since you can't use `await` in `Main` you should do that synchronously (although this is the only place that's acceptable):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TaskHelper helper = new TaskHelper();
    helper.StartProcessingAsync().Wait();
}
```

As Servy rightly pointed out, a more robust and production-ready solution would to use some kind of message loop. An example would be [Stephen Cleary's `AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TaskHelper helper = new TaskHelper();
    AsyncContext.Run(() => helper.StartProcessingAsync());
}
```

Notes:

- `async void` should never be used outside a UI event handler
- `async` method should generally be named `XAsync` (i.e. `StartProcessingAsync`)